# I am trying to deploy my node.js application into heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, nestjs

I am trying to deploy my node.js application into Heroku but when I try to push to Heroku branch my project I get:

```
remote: node_modules/@types/jsdom/base.d.ts:192:18 - error TS2411: Property '["Infinity"]' of type 'number' is not assignable to 'number' index type 'Window'.
remote: 
remote: 192         readonly ["Infinity"]: number;
remote:                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote: node_modules/@types/jsdom/base.d.ts:193:18 - error TS2411: Property '["NaN"]' of type 'number' is not assignable to 'number' index type 'Window'.
remote: 
remote: 193         readonly ["NaN"]: number;
remote:                      ~~~~~~~
remote: 
remote:        Found 2 error(s).
```

Node.Js version: v17.0.1
Npm version: 8.1.0

I developed this project with the nest.js framework, actually when I start in the local environment without problems.

Comment: I think this is an error in your TypeScript. Can you show the code?

Comment: Actually the error is in the @types/jsdom/base.d.ts, this is the node_module (dependency) of nestJS. It’s really strange because the error is present only when I try tu push to heroku main branch

Comment: Hmm, it may have been you were providing some wrong information to the lib? Can you show your code?

Comment: This is supposed to be fixed now but I have the same issue with `jest-environment-jsdom@29.0.3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying problem is that a transitive dependency was updated recently and that update isn't compatible with typescript. Also, I'm guessing your project isn't using a lock file, which if this is the case, is less than ideal.

For my nestjs project the problem was with a transitive dependency of jest. If you are using jest, see this github discussion to follow along and get updates as well as maybe get some tips on how to workaround it if you can't start using a lock file immediately https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/12098 (There seems to be a PR opened up in the underlying repo, but it might take some time to get approved and updated to npm's registry. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/57432)

If you don't have your package-lock.json file committed in your git repository you should add it. Heroku uses either package.json or package-lock.json to install your dependencies for you and if you want reproducible builds you should definitely use package-lock.json. If you have a package-lock.json file locally and it is currently git ignored, you can remove the entry in your .gitignore file.

See Heroku's docs for more info on how it handles package-lock.json: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#package-installation

> Heroku uses the lockfiles, either the package-lock.json or yarn.lock, to install the expected dependency tree, so be sure to check those files into git to ensure the same dependency versions across environments. If you are using npm, Heroku will use npm ci to set up the build environment.

Comment: This is supposed to be fixed now but I have the same issue with `jest-environment-jsdom@29.0.3`

Comment: I have this issue when building docker container even though I copy pnpm-lock.yaml to docker :/

Answer (score 1):

Using option `skipLibCheck: true` in tsconfig.json might be a temporary solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Do you know why I get this error in typescript, maybe? I mean the error is present in execution time when I push project into heroku branch (deploy)...

Comment: Agreed that `skipLibCheck: true` is a temporary solution that will get your build to go without errors this time, but I would only recommend it if it is definitely going to be temporary! If you are using typescript you really don't want to use this option.

Comment: @xunil the reason for the typescript error is that a transitive dependency of yours was updated (@types/jsdom) and that package had a couple of lines that are not typescript compatible.

Answer (score 0):

This is still an issue for me with Jest v29. Microsoft [even does some crazy workaround](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/pull/7987) to fix this issue.

Revert Jest and related dependencies to `v27.3.1` until fixed.